# how do I find my username in kali linux?

Tags: kali-linux

I installed kali and the next day after coming to work I forgot the username, I was able to find answers on how to change the password but not to get username info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get terminal access:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
```

This command will print a list of all users.

If you need to reset the user password, run:

```
passwd username
```

as root, where 'username' is your username.

To get root access, the default login is:

```
username: root
password: toor
```

If in doubt, as you've only recently installed Kali, you could consider reinstalling it

Comment: I got a very long list of "users" starting with root, daemon, bin, sys.......

Comment: @BenPettis Do you recognise any? You could also try: `cat /etc/passwd | grep /home`, which should return a shorter list. If you post the whole list I might be able to guess which is yours

Comment: after you command it says, ntp:x:112:114:: /home/ntp:/bin/false                          What does that mean?

Comment: @BenPettis 'ntp' is one of the usernames - the command, in this case, is to view usernames

Comment: @BenPettis If you edit your question to include the whole `cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd` output, I might be able to help you more

Comment: okay so Im going to type out the list

Comment: You can more simply list `ls -lrt /home`, which shows the home directories and the users who own them. The last (most recently updated) of these will most likely be for the user you created.

Comment: @AFH Good idea, I didn't think of that

Comment: @James - it saves ploughing through all the `/etc/password` entries. It assumes that the user has been created using normal home directory settings, which would almost certainly be the case for a user created during an installation.

Comment: @BenPettis If you're still typing, stop and do what AFH says instead - it should save a few hours ;)

Comment: root; daemon; bin;sys;sync;games;man;lp;mail;news; uucp;proxy;www-data; backup; list; irc; gnats; nobody; systemd-timesync; systemd-network, -resolve, -bus-proxy; _apt; mysql; epmd; debian-exim; uuidd; rwhod; iodine; miredo; ntp; stunne14; redsocks; rtkit; postgres; dnsmasq; messagebus; arpwatch; usbmux; debian-snmp; sslh; heoclue; couchdb; avahi; sshd; colord; saned; speech-dispatcher; pulse; king-phiser; debian-gdm; dradis; beef-xss

Comment: with ls lrt /home it says total 0

Comment: @BenPettis Oh maybe the user doesn't have a home directory then. From the list above are they any that you recognise?

Comment: no I don't recognize any

Comment: @BenPettis Then are you sure you actually made a user account? If you're using Kali, it's fairly normal to just use the root account. If you want to make a user account, run `adduser username`

Comment: i really don't know, I have another computer I installed it on that im using now that during install it prompted for username and password

Comment: @BenPettis You could try installing Kali elsewhere (for example a VM) and having a look at the list of users there. That might give you a clue to which users aren't default

Comment: thanks I did that add user and I logged in, can you tell me where to check for other users now

Comment: nevermind I did ls /home and it showed me that my username is username. do you know how I can change it?

Answer (score 0):

as root (or any user) in shell: `getent passwd`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.